# reusable angular components

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a search text box in an angular component that is used to search a list of names.
I would like to move this into a reusable component to avoid repeating the same code on multiple pages.
What is the best practice in doing this? Should I just generate a new component and move the logic there? I know there is a way to perform component interaction with @input decorations but I'm having trouble wrapping my head around how that would work in this scenario. Here is the following HTML and typescript code:

```
<input [ngModel]="searchStr" (ngModelChange)="employeeSearch($event)" class="form-control mb-3 pl-4" type="text"
        id="employeeName" placeholder="Employee Name" name="employeeName">


  employeeSearch(searchStr: string) {
    this.searchStr = searchStr;
    // some logic
  }
```

Comment: Use a generic component and keep the communication via input and ouput, if you want to take this outside your project build it using webcomponents.

Comment: You want to create custom form control which can be used anywhere in your project. Angular `ControlValueAccessor` will surely help you in this.
Refer the link for some example- https://indepth.dev/never-again-be-confused-when-implementing-controlvalueaccessor-in-angular-forms/

Answer (score 0):

As you already stated, you just create a new component and move the logic there.
Because you want to have the same list of employees in the application, you should introduce a service to your application, which stores/manipulates/etc. your list of employees. That service then should be used by your component.